# Copy column values using a partition by statement in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, aggregate-functions

In BigQuery, I am trying to copy column values into other rows using a PARTITION BY statement anchored to a particular ID number.

Here is an example:

[image]

Right now, I am trying to use:

```
MIN(col_a) OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(id AS STRING), date ORDER BY date) AS col_b
```

It doesn't seem like the aggregate function is working properly. As in, the "col_b" still has null values when I try this method. Am I misunderstanding how aggregate functions work?

Comment: you are missing `date` column in your example so it is hard to help yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
MIN(col_a) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS col_b
```

If you have one value per `id`, this will return that value.

Note that converting `id` to a string is unnecessary.  Also, you don't need a cumulative minimum, hence no `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `coalesce`

```
select *, coalesce(col_a, (select min(col_a) from my_table b where a.id=b.id)) col_b
from my_table a;
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3d359b87eeda1f0ef2af1c04d4651c51)